# Count string frequencies

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list with String frequencies:

[image]

I tried the excel function `FREQUENCIES()`. However this function requires a `bin`.

My goal is to get a frequency table of the city names.

I really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to get the answers is with a Pivot Table. First, insert a column above your list and enter something like "City" in D1. Select the whole column list, start a pivot table and drag the "City" field into the rows part of the pivot table. Drag the same thing to the main area and then select "Count" as the aggregate function.